# OSS license for seemingly unspecified license?

Tags: licensing

I want to work on uemacs/PK and run it through Coverity SCAN. I can see on the [repo](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/editors/uemacs/uemacs.git/log/) that there are commits by different people, but I'm confused because the README only allows modifications by a particular person.

```
    Full screen editor based on MicroEMACS 3.9e

    MicroEMACS was written by Dave G. Conroy and
    greatly modified by Daniel M. Lawrence

    Copyright Notices:

    MicroEMACS 3.9 (c) Copyright 1987 Daniel M. Lawrence.
    Reference Manual Copyright 1987 by Brian Straight and
    Daniel M. Lawrence. No copyright claimed for modifications
    made by Petri H. Kutvonen.

    Original statement of copying policy:

    MicroEMACS 3.9 can be copied and distributed freely for any
    non-commercial purposes. MicroEMACS 3.9 can only be incorporated
    into commercial software with the permission of the current author
    [Daniel M. Lawrence].
```

I read the [history](http://www.edm2.com/index.php/MicroEMACS), but I can't figure out the license (it says it's shareware), and Coverity needs a valid OS license to approve the project. I can't ask the original author because he passed away in 2010, so I don't know if he made additional exceptions to his license other that the one stated in the README, or the GPL licensing of JASSPA's.

What's the license for this project? May I modify the source for my non-commercial purposes? Would it be possible to have it approved by Coverity?

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [What is the “default” software license?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/26548/what-is-the-default-software-license)

Comment: I would suggest to work on GNU emacs or `qemacs`